# Python String Replace - "\" by "/"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace a string here in Python.

This is my Input -

```
MyString = \\ServerA\DriveB\5.FolderC\A.TXT
```

I want my output to be like this

```
OutputString = //ServerA/DriveB/5.FolderC/A.TXT
```

I tried the replace method it didn't work. Is there a function that can convert it ? Kindly help me with this.

The Code tried,

```
MyString = '\\ServerA\DriveB\5.FolderC\A.TXT'
Output_String = MyString.replace('\', '//')
print(Output_String)
```

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: @nullptr Yes replace works on a raw string by my string was a normal one. Thank You.

Comment: It seems you are working with OS paths. You might want to have a look into `pathlib` to deal with these kind of problems more or less automagically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`replace` should work.

```
my_string = r'\\ServerA\DriveB\5.FolderC\A.TXT'
my_string = my_string.replace('\\', '/')
```

Two things that commonly go wrong:

1. If you're not assigning back to a variable.
2. If you're not escaping the `\`.

Also, note that I'm using a raw string (using an `r` prefix) to make sure characters aren't escaped in the original string.