# How to search and replace character such as "\" in a file using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, text, replace, character

I have a text file where I want to replace the character `\` by `,`. After reading the answer of @Jack Aidley in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python):

```
# Read in the file
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('n', '***IT WORKED!!!***')

# Write the file out again
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

I could successfully change the content such as simple letter like `n` into `***IT WORKED!!!***`. However, if I replace

```
filedata.replace('n', '***IT WORKED!!!***')
```

by

```
filedata.replace('\', '***IT WORKED!!!***')
```

I get the syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

How can I replace all the `\` by `,`?

Comment: Python can't find the end of the string, because the backslash causes the following adjacent single-quote to get treated as an apostrophe within the string rather than the end of the string. If I want to store `you're` as a string between single-quotes, I have to type `'you\'re'`. Try `'\\'` (escaping the backslash) or `r'\'` (raw string).

Comment: Great! @dustintheglass: "\\" worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python String Replace - "\" by "/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329304/python-string-replace-by)