# change forward slash to backward slash in python

Tags: python

```
for category in categories:
  folder = os.path.join(directory, category)
  print(folder)
```

The output is:

```
C:\Users\Sibarani\OneDrive\Desktop\Data/cats
C:\Users\Sibarani\OneDrive\Desktop\Data/dogs
```

expected result is

```
C:\Users\Sibarani\OneDrive\Desktop\Data\cats
C:\Users\Sibarani\OneDrive\Desktop\Data\dogs
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329304/python-string-replace-by (I know it does the opposite of what you want, but the idea is the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is normally better to use forward slashes exclusively, this can be easily accomplished with `string.replace()`.

e.g.

```
for category in categories:
    folder = os.path.join(directory, category).replace("/", "\\")
    print(folder)
```

Comment: Would be better if you showed how to modify the string rather than just printing a temporary.

Comment: I believe I edited right after posting

Comment: Still not working plz help ---------

Comment: for category in categories:
  folder = os.path.join(directory, category).replace('/','\\')
  for img in os.listdir(folder):
    img_path = os.path.join(folder, img)
    print(img_path)
    break

Comment: FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-455e5a375e53> in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for category in categories:
      2   folder = os.path.join(directory, category).replace('/','\\')
----> 3   for img in os.listdir(folder):
      4     img_path = os.path.join(folder, img)
      5     print(img_path)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Sibarani\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Data\\cats'

Comment: @Sailex are you sure you're not missing an extension on that file name, like `.txt`?

Comment: @MarkRansom i figure it out. I was using google colab so i need to upload the files in my drive first. Silly mistakes....